# Why is this giving me an infinite loop?

Tags: java

I was going through a code used to calculate investments until it has doubled and I received an infinite loop that I can't seem to solve. Can anyone figure out why this is giving me an infinite loop? I've gone through myself but I can't seem to find the problem. The "period" referred is how many times per year the interest is compounded.

```
double account = 0; //declares the variables to be used
   double base = 0;
   double interest = 0;
   double rate = 0;
   double result = 0;
   double times = 0;
   int years = 0;
   int j;

   System.out.println("This is a program that calculates interest.");
   Scanner kbReader = new Scanner(System.in); //enters in all data  
   System.out.print("Enter account balance: ");
   account = kbReader.nextDouble();
   System.out.print("Enter interest rate (as decimal): ");
   rate = kbReader.nextDouble();

   System.out.println("                    " + "Years to double" + "     " +     "Ending balance");
   base = account;
   result = account;
   for (j=0; j<3; j++){
       System.out.print("Enter period: ");
       times = kbReader.nextDouble();
       while (account < base*2){
           interest = account * rate / times;
           account = interest + base;
           years++;
       }
        account = (((int)(account * 100))/100.0);
       //results
       System.out.print("                         " + i + "               " + account + "\n");
       account = result;
   }
```

The code should ask for three "periods", or three different times the entered data is compounded per year (ex annually, monthly, daily etc.)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: have you tried debugging this, setting a breakpoint in the code and stepping through it?

Comment: No, I'm relatively new with the IDE that I'm using, BlueJ. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: There's no guarantee that the cast to an `int` doesn't cause `account` to drop below the value of base.  If `base * 2 >= Integer.MAX_INTEGER`.  Also, since `times` is 0, I believe the `(int)` cast will always leave `Integer.MAX_INTEGER` in `account`.

Comment: I had it working earlier, then I bungled it and can't seem to figure out what happened. Ctrl-Z only takes me back so far.

Comment: Try printing the values of years, account, interest and the new value of account at each step. Pipe through less (or similar) and observe the results. If you wish, do a pen-and-paper simulation and compare the results to see if they agree.

Comment: @Sameer's got it. Stupid mistake. The code would never have reached base*2 if i went with the code that I had. Thanks to everybody anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing

```
account =interest +base
```

You should have

```
account = interest +account
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add some sanity checking. Either check if all the numbers will result in a finite number of loops (`account` and `rate` != 0, maybe some other stuff), or more simply, break if you've looped more times than would be reasonable (say 1000 for instance). My guess is that `rate` is `0` resulting in no increase in account, therefore it will loop forever.

You have a calculation error:

```
account = interest + base;
```

Presumably this should be:

```
account = account + interest;
```

Also, are you sure you want to have the int cast?

```
account = (((int)(account * 100))/100.0);
```

You're throwing away the values smaller than 1 cent apparently. However, if the interest is too small you will not get any change.

Comment: Well shouldn't the rate be changed when the user inputs a number? Anyway, I'll try that

Comment: @ChaseYuan Yes, but I was guessing maybe they typed in 0, or as Bohemian pointed out, a number too small.

Comment: Ok, so I've moved that to right before the code is printed out, so it shouldn't round until the very end.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it may loop forever is that the `double` calculation of `account` is effectively truncated by casting to `int`, so it may never change if `rate` is too small and the new value of `account` isn't made larger by at least `0.005`.

Comment: Perhaps, it could also be that rate was set to 0.